# Is there a way to move the caret by the moving the mouse?

Tags: bash, command-line

In both windows cmd and bash, I'd like to find a way to move the caret by moving the mouse. This would simplify editing the command line for me greatly.

Comment: ctl+a and ctl+e will get you to start and end of line at least on linux terminals...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any mouse support in bash. For [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/), get [zsh mouse support](http://stchaz.free.fr/mouse.zsh). This gives you cursor mouse movement in X terminals under X on Linux and other unices. It probably works on Windows with [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) zsh under unix-like terminals such as Cygwin's native rxvt, [Mintty](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/) or [PuTTYcyg](http://code.google.com/p/puttycyg/).

Answer (score 1):

You could try xdotool for bash.

```
xdotool getmouselocation
```

gives you the mouse location as a coordinate of your screen, you could probably script this to capture mouse motion... and then use

```
xdotool key
```

to get the corresponding direction key.

Basically, you can probably write a script to press the left direction key, for example, when the x coordinate of the mouse shifts by a certain number of pixels down. it depends on your screen resolution.

EDIT: This works for me on a horizontal direction. However, you need to think of a way to shut it down if u want it off. Closing the terminal would work.

```
while true; do horiz=$(xdotool getmouselocation | cut -d" " -f1 | grep -o [0-9]*); if [ ${horiz} -gt ${horiz2} ]; then xdotool key Right; elif [ ${horiz} -lt ${horiz2} ]; then xdotool key Left; fi ; horiz2=$horiz; done &
```

Comment: script is partly broken but I like the idea

Answer (score -1):

Not many of the newer terminals have mouse support, but I think xterm, rxvt and Eterm do.